# How do you use a try-catch in C (or the equivalent in C)

Tags: c

I need to figure out how to use a try catch equivalent to check if the user input too many characters, input a sign besides "+, -, *, /, or %" or if the user input something besides a 1 or 0 (in bits1 or bits2).

```
    printf("This program will do the equation (+, -, *, /, %) which a user will input, a 7bit binary number, a sign, and then another 7bit binary number and print the answer.\n\n");

    printf("Please enter the equation.\n");
    scanf("%7s%c%7s", bits1, &sign, bits2);
```

Comment: this have nothing to do with try-catch. you just need if statements

Comment: Trust me, you do not want to use `setjmp`/`longjmp`.

Comment: @HotLicks You beat me to it!  setjmp/longjmp is how to sorta do try-catch in C, but you don't want that here.

Comment: There is no good equivalent for exception handling (try/catch) in C, which is why it was added to C++.

Comment: Exceptions are not appropriate for checking “if the user input too many character” even if they were available. If you “tried using a do-while ” you need to post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `try-catch` in C. Just use `if` statements.

After the `scanf`, check

```
if(sign!='+' && sign!='-' && sign!='/' && sign!='*' && sign!='%') //if sign is an invalid character
    handle_bad_input();
else
{
    int i,len=strlen(bits1);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++) //for looping through each character
        if(bits1[i]!='0' && bits1[i]!='1') //if the character is not 0 or 1
            handle_bad_input();

    len=strlen(bits2);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        if(bits2[i]!='0' && bits2[i]!='1')
            handle_bad_input();
}
```

Note that in order for this to work as expected, `bits1` and `bits2` should be initialized. `scanf` might fail. So, as [@MattMcNabb](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) points out in the comments, checking the return value of `scanf` is a good idea. `scanf` returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file. And, if either happens before any data
could be successfully read, EOF is returned. In your case, it will return 3 when it is successful.

Comment: Also check the return value of scanf.